# WAV Audio File Repair with Audacity: Increase Speed and Remove Repeated Gaps

Tags: audio, repair, audacity, wav

I have a corrupt mono wav file: 16 bit PCM 44100Hz - mono.
It is a recording of 2 voices.

1. Voice 1 can be heard if the speed is increased by 5 times exactly.
2. Voice 2 is heard if the "gaps" / silences that appear every 80ms and last for 200ms are removed. The speed need not be changed.

That is in order for this file to be fixed, it has to be sped up 5 times so that the first voice is audible, and in order for the second voice to be normal those gaps have to be removed.

So far I have managed to do just 1 only.

So, the questions are:

1. How do I do #2 - i.e. how do I get rid of those inserted gaps that appear every 80ms and last for 200ms (Truncate silence effect did not help)?
2. How do I combine both fixes so that both voices are audible in a single file?

Comment: I'd start by duping the file. Then you are free to treat each separately & re-comp afterwards. #2 might be a manual task; idk Audacity well-enough

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But doing #2 manually is just impossible... 5-6 fragments per second for a total of 1 hour... that's like 10 000 K manual steps. Surely there must be a tool /filter for this.

Comment: might be a case of googling - I found this, but idk AVS at all - http://onlinehelp.avs4you.com/AVS-Audio-Editor/Working/EffectsFilters/Filters/DeleteSilence.aspx